# WKInterfaceTable inside WKInterfaceGroup with static BG image behind?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacegroup

I’m trying to display a static background image behind a scrolling `WKInterfaceTable`, that could contain one or more rows. I’m trying to do this by placing the table inside a `WKInterfaceGroup`, and setting that group’s background image. The issue is that if I set the group’s height to “Size to fit content”, the table will not scroll, and if I set the group’s height to “Relative to container”, the image does not take up the full display if there is only one row.

Is there a clever way around this problem? What I need is for the image to be the height of the display regardless of whether the number of rows is enough to scroll the table or not.

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't find the reference at the moment, an Apple employee in the developer forums has stated that having a static background image behind a scrolling table isn't possible with the current version of WatchKit.

Comment: I am tempted to downvote this perfect answer due the absurdity of the limitation

Comment: @Mazyod please open a rdar. If we complain in masses, Apple might add it in a future release.