# Apple watch scene Background scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

I am developing an app for Apple's new iWatch.

As its iWatch appilcation we must use `storyboard` with limited controls.

Our graphics team is asking to set Background in all the `scenes` in the `storyboard`.

We have successfully set `Background` property of `scene` but problem is when screen scrolls the background image also scrolls.

So my problem is simple i just want `groups` on my `scene` to scroll not the `Background` i set to scene.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. This answer was referring to table background, but is equally applicable here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29610011/3704092

WatchKit doesn't allow you to set z-index on UI elements, which is what you would need to pull off the effect you're looking for.