# Static Background with Scrolling Tables in Watchkit for Xcode (Apple Watch)

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I needed to know if it was possible with the release of WatchOS2 to be able to have a static background image that doesn't move while having a table overlay that is scrollable. All I can find online is that it wasn't possible in the original WatchOS. Thanks to whoever can answer this!

Link to Stackoverflow original WatchOS post.
[Apple watch scene Background scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076816/apple-watch-scene-background-scrolls)

Answer (score 0):

It's still not possible in watchOS3. Please open an enhancement issue at the [Apple Bug Reporter System](http://bugreporter.apple.com).